# Hide a subfolder in the url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am using this url:

```
http://example.com/folder/form.php
```

I want whenever someone uses this link to change the URL shown to

```
http://example.com/form.php
```

So far I have done that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1
```

BUT, I dont want this rule to apply when someone uses

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

So I need to make this rule work only when the url is like

```
http://example.com/form.php
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want your `/index.php` file to redirect to `/folder` you can exclude it in the pattern or using a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ folder/ [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index.php).*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ folder/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1
```

Comment: What I want is not redirect. Here is an example of what I want.

Comment: Lets say a user asks for the index.php file. Nothing will happen. If they ask for the /folder/form.php file, I want the /folder part to be hidden in the URL. I don't even know if this is possible because, what will happen if they refresh the page? Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @CharosMoutafidis The rule I posted rewrites any incoming uris (except index.php) from `/root folder` to `/subfolder` meaning that ,you can access `/foder/file.php` using a short url `/file.php` .